# asking for numbers in python and returning a list

Tags: python

Hey guys I'm stuck on one part of an exercise. What I am supposed to do is ask for a number (the exercise says I need to enter the numbers (4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22, -9999) with -9999 being the breaking number. It is supposed to make 3 lists. list a is all numbers entered, list p is all positive numbers and list n is all negative numbers. This is the code I have so far:

```
a = []
p = []
n = []
total = -9999

while(True):
    user_input = int(input('Please enter a number:'))
    if(user_input == -9999):
    break
elif(user_input >= 0):
    p.append(user_input)
elif(user_input <= 0):
    n.append(user_input)


 a = p + n
 print('The list of all numbers entered is:', '\n', a)
```

when I run this program and use these numbers I get [4, 0, 10, 22, -3, -15] which is correct but when I looked at the answer for this exercise it has the numbers in a different order [4, -3, -15, 0, 10, 22]. I'm stuck on how to get the numbers in this order.

One more quick question. On part b of this exercise I am supposed to find the avg of all numbers, positive numbers and negative numbers. When I print a, p, n it does not add 0 to the negative list even though I have the user_input <= 0 which will throw off the average. What am I missing?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Better you post the exercise question as it is to let us understand the problem clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part use this

```
while(True):
    user_input = int(input('Please enter a number:'))
    if(user_input == -9999):
        break
    elif(user_input >= 0):
        p.append(user_input)
    elif(user_input <= 0):
        n.append(user_input)
    #always append to a, makes the order the same as input order.
    a.append(user_input)
```

(The identation problem is bad copy paste I assume)
For the second part you can make the elif like this to make it work for 0

```
    elif(user_input >= 0):
        p.append(user_input)
    if(user_input <= 0 and user_input != -9999):
        n.append(user_input)
```

The reason it failed is because once it is stored in p, it skips the remaining elif else blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Your indentation is bad coded. As result, the two elif setences are not running inside your while loop. Try the following code.

```
a = []
p = []
n = []
total = -9999

while(True):
    user_input = int(input('Please enter a number:'))
    if(user_input == -9999):
    break
    elif(user_input >= 0):
        p.append(user_input)
    elif(user_input <= 0):
        n.append(user_input)


 a = p + n
 print('The list of all numbers entered is:', '\n', a)
```